# Note taking software

Tags: software-recommendation, software-center

So I am a CS student and work a lot on programming usually on a Linux machine. I have Linux installed on a partition of my laptop, and lately I have been thinking of making the full switch to Ubuntu. However, there is one application that I need to be able to use and the only Linux application I have found similar to it is nowhere near as 'powerful'. That program is onenote, and I know there are many alternatives to onenote but I have a thinkpad yoga with a digitzer pen so I can write on my screen. I know I can get the digitizer to work but I am looking for a good replacement for the onenote digitizer note taking capabilities.

Thanks!

Edit: So My question is more focused on finding an app that lets me take handwritten notes on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Xournal? Using a Wacom bamboo, I can take handwritten notes, edit and move text later, change color and thickness of lines, insert and resize images, use auto-shape correction for graphs or the occasional schematic. In addition, you can also use it to annotate pdfs and then export it as a pdf.